# Blank Customer adding automatically in backend - Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.9

in Magento 1.8 daily 10 to 20 customers are automatically adding into our backend,
We are not using any public form for customer

Any Security patches recommended ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling captcha for the customer registration form? You can do this under System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > CAPTCHA. I understand that you may not have a public registration form available... but post requests still can be submitted to the registration URL. So please try enabling CAPTCHA and then will see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all security patches are recommended. Given you are on 1.8 and customers are created without email in the global scope, there certainly could be a security issue.

I built a small tool a few years back that helps getting the right patches. It might be a little bit outdated now but couldn't harm to run it and see what patches it downloads for your store.

https://github.com/frosit/magepatch

Besides that you could check your access logs for any POST request around the time of creation. If you find what path they use to create them, you could block that using htaccess / nginx config. Logs are usually in  /var/log/apache or nginx/access.log*. You can find plenty examples on how to use grep for this around stack.

The captcha mentioned in the comments is also a good idea, even more if you're behind on patches.